# How to count the number of connected values in a matrix?

Tags: performance, search, matrix, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given a 2D array of integers, how can I find the size of the biggest group of connected values? Connected in this context only counts up/down/left/right, no diagonals. For example, the following array has **four** 3's connected:
8 **3 3 3**
1 2 **3** 8
1 2 5 6
6 2 3 9

I don't want to use the brute force method of applying a floodfill search on every element in the matrix.

Additionally, how would I also solve the same problem with a twist: find the size of the biggest cluster in the matrix. A cluster must contain two values (no more, no less). For example, in the same matrix, the biggest cluster would be of 3's and 2's, and the size of the cluster is **8**.
8 **3 3 3**
1 **2 3** 8
1 **2** 5 6
6 **2 3** 9

Comment: Surely you can't do better than a simple linear traversal in the worst case.

Comment: Use a modified neighbors function. Show what you tried. Also one question per post please

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive neighbors method to retrieve the number of neighbors in each group:

```
public class TestNeighbors{

    private static int[][] nodes = new int[][] {
                                      {8, 3, 3, 3},
                                      {1, 2, 3, 8},
                                      {1, 2, 5, 6},
                                      {6, 2, 3, 9}
                                    };
    private static int rows = nodes.length, cols = nodes[0].length;
    private static boolean[][] visited = new boolean[rows][cols];
    private static int[][] dirs = {{-1,0},{1,0},{0,-1},{0,1}};  //directions

    public static void main(String [] args){

        for(int row =0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col =0; col < cols; col++){
                int n = neighbors(row, col);
                if(n>0) {
                    System.out.println(row + "-"+ col+" has " +n 
                    + " neighbors of the same value ("+nodes[row][col]+")");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int neighbors(int row, int col) {
        return neighbors(row, col,0);
    }

    private static int neighbors(int row, int col, int numberOfNeighbors ) {

        if(! withinBounds(row, col)) { return 0;}
        visited[row][col] = true;

        //find neighbors by iterating directions
        for( int[] dir : dirs) {
            int neighborRow = row + dir[0]; //neighbor row 
            int neighborCol = col + dir[1];//neighbor col 
            //chaeck if valid row col
            if(! withinBounds(neighborRow, neighborCol)) { continue;}
            //check for the same value 
            if(nodes[row][col] != nodes[neighborRow][neighborCol]) { continue;}
            //check if it has not been accounted for
            if(visited[neighborRow][neighborCol]) { continue;}

            numberOfNeighbors++;
            numberOfNeighbors =
                    neighbors(neighborRow, neighborCol, numberOfNeighbors);
        }

        return numberOfNeighbors;
    }

    //check address is within grid bounds
    private static boolean withinBounds(int row, int col) {
        if ((row < 0) || (row >= rows) || (col< 0) || (col >= cols)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 0-1 has 3 neighbors of the same value (3)
>  1-0 has 1 neighbors of
>   the same value (1)
>  1-1 has 2 neighbors of the same value (2)

Comment: Feedback would be appreciated